# Why for the closed string we need to take both left and right moving modes into account when deriving the mass?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, string-theory

In the closed bosonic string we have both left and right moving sectors with modes $\alpha_m^\mu$ and $\tilde{\alpha}_m^\mu$ respectively where $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ and where we have $\alpha_0^\mu = \tilde{\alpha}_0^\mu = \frac{\ell_s}{2}p^\mu$. Now the Virasoro generators are given by

$$L_m=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \alpha_{m-n}\cdot \alpha_n,\quad \tilde{L}_m=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \tilde\alpha_{m-n}\cdot \tilde\alpha_n\tag{1}$$

and classically the vanishing of the energy-momentum tensor requires $L_m = \tilde{L}_m =0$. Now it is said in some references (for example Becker, Becker & Schwarz, page 40) that to get the mass formula $M^2$ for the classical closed string we need to take both left-moving and right-moving modes into account. I don't get this, my impression is that we *can* obtain $M^2$ from just $L_0=0$ or $\tilde{L}_0=0$. Indeed:

$$L_0 = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \alpha_{-n}\cdot \alpha_n = \frac{1}{2}\alpha_0^2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\alpha_{-n}\cdot \alpha_n +\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_{-n}\cdot \alpha_n=-\frac{\ell_s^2}{8}M^2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_{-n}\cdot \alpha_n\tag{2}$$

where in the third equality we have reindexed $m =-n$ in the first sum, used that the classical variables commute and used the definition of $\alpha_0$. When we set $L_0 =0$ we are able to get $$M^2=\frac{8}{\ell_s^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_{-n}\cdot \alpha_n\tag{3}.$$

Now the same derivation in (2) with $\tilde{L}_0$ gives $$M^2=\frac{8}{\ell_s^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tilde{\alpha}_{-n}\cdot \tilde{\alpha}_n\tag{4},$$

and clearly if we sum them up and divide by two we find  $$M^2=\frac{4}{\ell_s^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\alpha_{-n}\cdot \alpha_n+\tilde{\alpha}_{-n}\cdot \tilde{\alpha}_n\right)\tag{5}.$$

My impression is that we can express $M^2$ either in terms of just $\alpha_m$ as in (3), equivalently in terms of just $\tilde{\alpha}_n$ as in (4) or in terms of both as in (5). But still, as I said, some references say that for the closed string we need *both* $L_0=0$ and $\tilde{L}_0=0$ to derive the mass. What am I missing here? We do we need both $L_0=0$ and $\tilde{L}_0=0$ to derive the mass formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need to take both left- and right-moving modes. OP's equations $(3)$ and $(4)$ are both correct - the mass can be expressed as a sum over one set of modes only:
   $$
   M^2=\frac4{\alpha'}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_n\cdot\alpha_{-n}=\frac4{\alpha'}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\tilde\alpha_n\cdot\tilde\alpha_{-n}
   $$
2. $L_0=0$ and $\tilde L_0=0$ - and more generally, $L_n=0$, $\tilde L_n=0$ - due to the vanishing of the independent energy-momentum tensor components $T_{--}=0$ and $T_{++}=0$, respectively. The equivalence $L_0=\tilde L_0$ is needed in the classical formula only if one wishes to express the mass in terms of both sets of oscillators.

   In the quantum theory, however, assuming a non-compact background for simplicity, the fact that $\hat L_0\simeq \hat{\tilde{L}}_0$ when acting on physical states implies level matching: $N=\tilde N$, and also ensures that the mass-squared matches between left-movers and right-movers.

Comment: i thought the $L_0 - \tilde{L}_0=0$ constraint arises because of a topological obstruction (the Euler number), so i’m not sure why a normal ordering constant has anything to do with this - i may be missing something obvious; can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Wakabaloola My point was that the fact that $L_0=\tilde L_0$ plays no significant role in the classical theory, while in the quantum theory, $L_0-a=\tilde L_0-a$ *is* important because it imposes the level matching constraint. I did not mean that was *how* they arose, only that it is an effect. I'm not sure what topological obstruction you're referring to though.

Comment: you seem to be saying that you enforce level matching to cancel the normal ordering constant. the obstruction i’m referring to is that the phase of a local coordinate is not globally defined, so this phase better cancel out of physical vertex operators. it is the same as the obstruction underlying the hairy ball theorem(but for arbitrary topologies). by cutting open the path integral across separating degenerations one can also prove that there exists a projection onto level matched asymptotic states. for details and elaboration on all of this see https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.01055.

Comment: @Wakabaloola sorry, but I don't know exactly which part of your paper is relevant. Is it incorrect to say $(\hat L_0-a)|\phi\rangle=(\hat{\tilde L}_0-a)|\phi\rangle\implies \hat N=\hat{\tilde N}, M^2_L=M^2_R$? This is the point I was trying to make in my answer.

Comment: hi @NiharKarve; if you say (and i quote) `this "level matching" constraint serves to cancel the normal-ordering constant.', then it can lead one to conclude that one imposes level matching in order to cancel the normal ordering constant; but this is (as far as I understand) wrong, and therefore misleading for a novice reading your answer. So perhaps you meant to write something slightly different; I don't know why you are mentioning the normal ordering constant in the first place.

Comment: @Wakabaloola you are correct, and I will edit the post; it was indeed poorly worded

Comment: There are a few ways of seeing why imposing level matching is a good thing, two of which are the following: 1) if you impose level matching then this ensures all the tensor indices are properly contracted in order to get something reparametrisation-invariant (e.g., see Weinberg's 1985 article on vertex operators); 2) the phase generated by acting with $L_0-\tilde{L}_0$ on a local vertex operator is in any case not globally-defined..

Comment: .. To define a phase you need two non-zero (e.g., unit) tangent vectors. But Hopf's index theorem says that globally-defined tangent vector *must* vanish at a discrete set of points on a general Riemann surface, and therefore the corresponding phase cannot be defined everywhere on the surface either. (see, e.g, the discussion beginning on page 82 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.01055.pdf)

Comment: @Wakabaloola Thanks! (and edited)

Comment: regarding your last edit note that $L_0=\tilde{L}_0$ implies $N=\tilde{N}$ *only when* $p_L^2=p_R^2$ (e.g. only when spacetime is non-compact, or in particular when there is no winding or no momentum modes in the compact dimensions).

Comment: tori are also flat backgrounds but compact and can carry non-trivial winding, so perhaps you meant to instead write `assuming non-compact backgrounds for simplicity` instead of 'flat backgrounds'